# A NSString question?

Tags: ios

I have a C string, it is encoded with UTF-7, like `"+g0l6P3ux-"`.

I can decode the string with Python. But when I use:

```
[NSString stringWithCString:"+g0l6P3ux-" encoding:kCFStringEncodingUTF7];
```

it returns `nil`, why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you use

```
+ (id)stringWithCString:(const char *)cString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc
```

expects NSStringEncoding, and if you look up NSStringEncoding in the docs,  kCFStringEncodingUTF7 is not a valid value.

Instead of

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:"+g0l6P3ux-" encoding:kCFStringEncodingUTF7];
```

you could use

```
CFStringRef cfstr = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "+g0l6P3ux-", kCFStringEncodingUTF7);
NSString *str = [(NSString *)cfstr copy];
CFRelease(cfstr);
```

Comment: Actually, you can do a simple cast without the need to copy: `NSString *str = (NSString *)CFStringCreateWithCString(...);` and you get a retained string. `NSString *` and `CFStringRef` may safely be cast to each other thanks to toll-free bridging.

Comment: Yes, true. I was looking here: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CFStringRef and I was under the impression that memory management stuff wasn't "toll free", but looking here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002401-767858 it's clear that it is.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get correct text with this lines of code - initial text was in UTF 7 (mail folder path in russian):

```
const char *stringAsChar = [folder.folderPath cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:stringAsChar encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingUTF7_IMAP)];
```